# Equivalent of D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile in Windows 8 SDK?

Tags: windows-8, directx-11

I am wondering what would the equivalent be of creating a Shader Resource View from a file with the windows 8 SDK?

I looked up D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile on MSDN.. says it's deprecated, and to use CreateXXSFromFile (where XXS is DDS, so in my case CreateDDSFromFile) (in DirectXTK library) instead...

But I can't find any documentation on it whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should use CreateXXXTextureFromFile. DirectXTex website contains samples and documentation with details. For example CreateDDSTextureFromFile is described here: http://directxtex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DDSTextureLoader.